# WKWebView: How to disable data detection and automatic link detection on macOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, datadetectortypes

The key here is **macOS**, not iOS.

Data detection can easily be disabled on iOS via [WKWebViewConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1641937-datadetectortypes), but this property is not available on macOS.

Background:

I have a `WKWebView` embedded in a macOS app that shows a contenteditable DIV. I would like to prevent that links are automatically detected as the user types and turned into hyperlinks.